# lxml data from two tags

Tags: python, lxml

My code is like this

```
response = urllib2.urlopen("file:///C:/data20140801.html")
page = response.read()
tree = etree.HTML(page)

data = tree.xpath("//p/span/text()")
```

html page could have this structures

```
<span style="font-size:10.0pt">Something</span>
```

html page could also have this structures

```
<p class="Normal">
    <span style="font-size:10.0pt">Some</span>
    <span style="font-size:10.0pt">thing<span>
</p>
```

Using same code for both I want to get "Something"

Comment: You changed the entire premise of the question now.

Comment: What is the issue here? That you have some that are in a `<p>` tag and some are not? Why should the `<span>` text in the `<p>` tag be joined while the other is not? *How are they distinct*?

Answer (score 2):

The XPath expression returns a *list* of values:

```
>>> from lxml.html import etree
>>> tree = etree.HTML('''\
... <p class="Normal">
...     <span style="font-size:10.0pt">Some</span>
...     <span style="font-size:10.0pt">thing<span>
... </p>
... ''')
>>> tree.xpath("//p/span/text()")
['Some', 'thing']
```

Use `''.join()` to combine the two strings into one:

```
>>> ''.join(tree.xpath("//p/span/text()"))
'Something'
```

Comment: Sorry, My question was unclear,so please check the edit

Comment: @DexterStack: that is an *entirely different question*.

Comment: @DexterStack: your new question is now too vague to answer.